# Magento Paypal onAuthorization error on return to success page

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-fpm

I have a fresh install of Magento 2.3.6. I enabled the default paypal payment method, and I am trying to debug it using sandbox mode.

I am able to complete the process of the payment on Paypal, but when it suppose to return to the site, it just hangs on `Processing...` in Paypal site (see image below), and in devtools I see that there is a request to magento url `paypal/express/onAuthorization` that is pending.

[image]

After exactly 60 seconds, I am getting an error in the UI:

[image]

The backend is using nginx->php-pfm setup. In nginx log I see error 499:

```
10.244.43.27 - - [30/Apr/2021:14:54:06 +0000] "POST /index.php/paypal/express/onAuthorization/ HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://example.com/index.php/checkout/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36" "10.244.43.0, 10.244.226.77
```

The onAuthorization link is showing 504 error:

[image]

There is nothing in php-pfm that correlates to that time. There is nothing relevant in var/log/* files.

The payment on Paypal is actually successful. The seller account received the payment.

I also enabled debug on magento config for (Sales=>Paypal=>Advanced=>Debug mode), and I see, about 10 seconds after the confirmation of the pay on paypal site, `var/log/payment.log` with a response of  `'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS' => 'Completed'`.

I tried to increase timeouts both in nginx and in php-pfm.

php-pfm:

```
# php -i | grep timeout
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
Read timeout => 86400
default_socket_timeout => 600 => 600
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
```

nginx:

```
# grep fastcgi_read_timeout /var/www/html/magento2.conf 
        fastcgi_read_timeout 100s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
```

How to debug this from here?

Answer (score 1):

After a month of debugging, we were able to find the cause of the problem. The issue was that backend process took 5 minutes to complete. For some reason the order confirmation email of Magneto took 4 minutes. Disabling all emails in the admin dashboard (Stores => Configurations => Sales => Sales emails) Solved the problem.

To debug the problem we used 'strace' to trace the actual calls.